# Bluemix Secure Gateway Monitor

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

It is possible to monitor and get an alert by email when the service fails?
for example, I had the following problems:

The Secure Gateway tunnel is disabled and disconnected, it must be reconnected before re-enabled
Waiting for the Secure Gateway tunnel to be re-enabled...

The Secure Gateway tunnel was disconnected
Secure Gateway tunnel retry activation in five seconds
The Secure Gateway tunnel connection was refused
The following errors occurred on the Secure Gateway tunnel, ETIMEDOUT...

Comment: I have submitted this idea on the Bluemix ideas site at the following URL:
http://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas/suggestions/11421057-notify-you-by-email-if-a-service-fails

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we do not have a feature for sending alerts, though that could be a nice addition in the future.

As for the errors that you encountered with the client, updating to 1.4.0 should solve that issue for them. Thank you!